# How To Capture and Format Json Response in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, curl, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm running a curl command in my Jenkinsfile.

```
    post {
      success {
        script {
            sh '''
            |SCORE=+1
            |GERRIT_COMMENT="$(cat <<-EOL
            |Sonar result was: SUCCESS
            |Report: ${Jenkins_URL}/job/${JOB_NAME}/${BUILD_NUMBER}/artifact/report1.txt
            |EOL
            |)"
            |curl -s -u ${apiToken}: ${Sonar_URL}/api/measures/component_tree?ps=100&s=qualifier,name&component=sonarqube&metricKeys=ncloc,bugs,vulnerabilities,code_smells,security_hotspots,coverage,duplicated_lines_density&strategy=children | json_pp -json_opt pretty,canonical > report1.txt
            |echo "Voting unsuccessful"
            '''.stripMargin().stripIndent()
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'report1.txt', fingerprint: true
            echo 'I Succeeded'
            }
    }
```

But I get the error
`malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "(end of string)") at /usr/bin/json_pp`

I can't use **jq** as it's not installed and installing it isn't an option.

The curl command works fine on my terminal but is failing in my Jenkins pipeline.

Also, when I do this instead, it works.

```
    post {
      success {
        script {
            sh '''
            |SCORE=+1
            |GERRIT_COMMENT="$(cat <<-EOL
            |Sonar result was: SUCCESS
            |Report: ${Jenkins_URL}/job/${JOB_NAME}/${BUILD_NUMBER}/artifact/report1.txt
            |EOL
            |)"
            |echo "Voting unsuccessful"
            '''.stripMargin().stripIndent()
            sh """
            curl -s -u ${apiToken}: '${Sonar_URL}/api/measures/component_tree?ps=100&s=qualifier,name&component=sonarqube&metricKeys=ncloc,bugs,vulnerabilities,code_smells,security_hotspots,coverage,duplicated_lines_density&strategy=children' | json_pp -json_opt pretty,canonical > report1.txt
            """
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'report1.txt', fingerprint: true
            echo 'I Succeeded'
            }
    }
```

But it throws a warning in the console output.

`Warning: A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure. Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [apiToken]`

What am I doing wrong, please?

In a Jenkins pipeline, how would you properly pass a JSON response using curl into a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to not use shell scripts whenever it is possible. Shell scripts are not cross platform and require installing additional tools (e.g. `curl`).

In your case the `curl` call could be replaced by the [httpRequest](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/#httprequest-perform-an-http-request-and-return-a-response-object) step.

First let's replace the `curl` call and saves the result in a `componentTree.json` file:

```
httpRequest(
    url: "${Sonar_URL}/api/measures/component_tree?ps=100&s=qualifier,name&component=sonarqube&metricKeys=ncloc,bugs,vulnerabilities,code_smells,security_hotspots,coverage,duplicated_lines_density&strategy=children",
    authorization: 'id-of-credentials-which-was-used-to-create-the-apiToken-variable',
    outputFile: 'componentTree.json'
)
```

You want to format the JSON data in a human-readable format, so let's use the [readJSON](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace) and [writeJSON](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#writejson-write-json-to-a-file-in-the-workspace) steps:

```
def json = readJSON(file: 'componentTree.json')
writeJSON(json: json, file: 'report1.txt', pretty: 4)
```

Now the `report1.txt` file contains JSON formatted with indent 4.

The `componentTree.json` file is written and read only once, so let's decrease the number of the IO operations:

```
def response = httpRequest(
    url: "${Sonar_URL}/api/measures/component_tree?ps=100&s=qualifier,name&component=sonarqube&metricKeys=ncloc,bugs,vulnerabilities,code_smells,security_hotspots,coverage,duplicated_lines_density&strategy=children",
    authorization: 'id-of-credentials-which-was-used-to-create-the-apiToken-variable'
)
def json = readJSON(text: response.content)
writeJSON(json: json, file: 'report1.txt', pretty: 4)
```

---

About the warning:

> Warning: A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure. Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [apiToken]

Secrets never should be interpolated because they may contain special characters which could be interpreted. Example:

- my secret: `My' https://example.org; cat /etc/passwd; echo \`
- command: `curl -u '${password}' https://private.server/path/file.txt`

After the interpolation the following command is called:

```
curl -u 'My' https://example.org; cat /etc/passwd; echo \' https://private.server/path/file.txt
```

There are two options to fix it:

- if `apiToken` is an environment variable:

  ```
  sh "curl -s -u \$apiToken: '${Sonar_URL}/api/measures/component..."
  ```
- if `apiToken` is a Groovy variable:

  ```
  withEnv(["CREDENTIALS=${apiToken}"]) {
      sh "curl -s -u \$CREDENTIALS: '${Sonar_URL}/api/measures/component..."
  }
  ```

In both cases the dollar sign (`$`) is escaped before the credentials which means that shell script will resolve it (it will be taken from environment variables).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Agabrys. I've tried this solution on my private Jenkins instance and it works a charm. 


Unfortunately, the Jenkins server I'm actually working on doesn't have the `http_request` plugin installed, 

so it looks like I'm stuck with having to use curl.  I just don't know how to get beyond the `A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure. Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [apiToken]` error.                    I've learned something new though.. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I added the explanation why credentials shouldn't be passed by using String interpolation.